# Most efficient way to return True or False if a function input is within specified range? (Efficiency Problem)

Tags: python, function, return, range, coding-efficiency

So I just finished a section exam for my Python course and one of the challenge questions given was to write a function that would return True if the function input was within 10 of either 100 or 200.

I came up with a a function that works, however, I KNOW that I'm missing some efficiency.

Here is the function I originally tried:

```
def numfunc(a):
    range_list = list(range(90,111)) + list(range(190,211))
    for num in range_list:
        if a != num:
            continue
        elif a == num:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

The problem with the above code was that it would return True if the number was in range, however, if it wasn't, it would return nothing.

The function I wrote that finally worked was this:

```
def numfunc(a):
    range_list = list(range(90,111)) + list(range(190,211))
    answer = []
    
    for num in range_list:
        if a == num:
            answer.append(True)
            
    if answer == [True]:
        return True
    
    if answer != [True]:
        return False
```

Keep in mind that I'm using what functions I've either learned myself or have gone over in the course.

So if anyone can point out why the first block of code wasn't returning False and/or could teach me a more efficient way to accomplish the same thing: I'd love to learn from you.

Comment: You can just ask if `x in range(a, b)`.

Comment: For your first function: remove `else:` then *un-indent* `return False` till it is not in the loop.

Comment: @hilbert. No you can't

Comment: @MadPhysicist I am not saying that this solves the problem. I meant to suggest that `x in range(a, b)` is preferable to `x in list(range(a, b))`.

Comment: You're never going to hit the last `else` because you've already tested both possible conditions.

Comment: `return a in {90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that `if a != num: continue` prevents anything else from happening if the numbers don't match. The loop will reach its end, and the function will return the default value of None.

The simple fix is to write the loop like this:

```
for num in range_list:
    if == num:
        return True
return False
```

Notice that the final return is outside the loop.

But from an efficiency point of view, testing for containment in a range by checking integer elements is a terrible idea. Use rich comparison operators instead:

```
def numfunc(a):
    return abs(a - 100) <= 10 or abs(a - 200) <= 10
```

The equivalent expression not using `abs` would be

```
def numfunc(a):
    return -10 <= a - 100 <= 10 or -10 <= a - 200 <= 10
```

Comment: OH! Haven't read up on absolute values yet. You're 'absolute'ly right. This is much more efficient if I'm understanding the theory correctly. Essentially you're telling Python to return True or False based on the absolute value in relation to the numbers that I'm running the input against. So if "a - 100 or 200 is less than or equal to an absolute value of 10 return true, if not false." My follow up question would be, is it because we are using comparison operators that you know abs will return True of False?

Comment: The expression `abs(a - 100)` evaluates to an integer or a float. The operator `<` will reopen a boolean when applied to that result.

Answer (score 4):

You can used a chained comparison to do this in one expression:

```
def f(a):
    return 90<=a<=110 or 190<=a<=210

print(f(200))
print(f(90))
print(f(150))
```

Result:

```
True
True
False
```

Comment: Wow, didn't realize this would return true or false without having to specify to return them. Thanks a alot.

Comment: The expression evaluates to either `True` or `False`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a number `n` is in range of 2 numbers you should use range to check it with this returning true or false. What you are doing is creating a list based on two lists and those lists aren't creating a list from 90 to 211 they are creating a list that contain numbers from 90 to 110  and 190 to 210.

Also if you want to check if a number exists in a list just use:

```
if n in list:
   return True
```

This should work:

```
def numFunc(a):
        print(a in range(0,100))
    
numFunc(2)
numFunc(101)
numFunc(20)
```

Output:

```
True
False
True
```